# Automatically Resetting the Current Workspace on Startup

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, workspace

I'm looking for a way to force InDesign to reset its current workspace when I start the program. I have created the jsx script below and placed it into the startup scripts folder. It does a great job of applying the workspace, but it doesn't actually reset it. So if I move a panel, then apply a different workspace and close InDesign, it will apply the correct workspace when I restart InDesign, but the panel is still moved. I have tried playing around with the language, using "app.reset" or "app.refresh" but those are just failed guesses. I have not been able to find the right commands to perform a proper workspace reset. 
I'm not married to this approach, either. A script that would send a key command to reset the workspace would be fine as well. **I already have a key command assigned to the the function**, but I would prefer to have it reset on its own upon startup. Any other approaches to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
try{  
app.applyWorkspace("MyWorkspaceName");  
}catch(e)  
{  
    alert(  
        "Fail:"+"\r"+  
        "Slap yourself and try again."  
        )  
};
```

FYI: The reason I'm doing this is because InDesign has a bug that causes some panels to be dismissed. Adobe fixed the problem for a short period, but now it's back.

Comment: Hi. I can't find any reference for a reset workspace method. However, I regularly have trouble with messed up workspace and what I do is trashing the cache. On Windows, delete "InDesign SavedData" file located on C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Adobe\InDesign\Version xxxxx\lang_LANG\Caches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset by invoking the menu item:

```
try{  
    var myWorkspace = "MyWorkspaceName";
    app.applyWorkspace( myWorkspace ); 
    app.menuActions.item( "$ID/Reset " + myWorkspace ).invoke();
}
catch(e) {  
    alert( e );
};
```

**Some great info on invoking menu items in Indesign:**
http://kasyan.ho.ua/tips/indesign_script/all/open_menu_item.html

Answer (score 0):

ermm...

- **`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`**
- Under `Product Area` change the drop down to **`Window Menu`**
- Scroll down.. way down near the bottom.. find **Workspace: Reset [yourWorkspaceName]** and highlight that item
- In the text field below, enter a **New Shortcut**

Click `OK` (save the Set if prompted).. your shortcut will call the "Reset" command.

You don't need javascript.

Comment: I don't think you read my question in its entirety. I already have a shortcut assigned. I'm looking for a way to automatically reset the workspace when I start InDesign, without having to initiate it manually. I also said that I don't necessarily need the solution to be javascript, and that I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

#targetengine "session"

app.eventListeners.add("afterActivate", setWorkspace);

function setWorkspace(e){
var menuItem =  app.menuActions.itemByID(91219)
if(menuItem.enabled){
menuItem.invoke();
};
app.removeEventListener("afterActivate", setWorkspace);
}